# How can I go about user-testing my website if I don't have a budget for it?

Tags: usability-testing, feedback

Useful outputs could include feedback in the form of user feedback via written reviews, video, etc.

Comment: @JonW I believe the edit I made to this question fits the "...instead, try to ask a focused question about a particular aspect of the design..." directive (in this case, it's a reframe asking about process). Can you re-open? If you disagree, could you clarify why so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although sites like this are often very useful, and fivesecondtest.com in particular if you don't have a budget, you may also just want to do a screen share/take notes if you don't have a budget. I've done valuable usability testing with Skype or join.me. You can also record these experiences for free with quicktime screen Video Recording feature. If that's important for your documentation, just also make sure to properly set-up audio recording also. These types of usability tests are often quick and dirty, but they will undoubtedly give you a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, always make it easy for users to provide feedback, send comments or request enhancements. Although your product may not be perfect right now it is an ongoing process and its important to get feedback from real life users. This is the only feedback that is really worth listening to.

You can use a tool like this for prototyping: http://cogtool.hcii.cs.cmu.edu/

From the home page:

> CogTool is a general purpose UI prototyping tool with a difference -
>   it automatically evaluates your design with a predictive human
>   performance model (a "cognitive crash dummy").